# Showing whether a intial arrangement of numbers (odd/even) is sortable according to the constraint on sorting each time.

Tags: combinatorics, parity

Let $P$ denote some arrangement of the numbers $1,2, \ldots, n$. A move on $P$ consists of exchanging the position of element 1 with the position of another element. For example, if $P=[3,1,4,2]$, then by making one move we can get either $P=[1,3,4,2]$, $P=[3,4,1,2]$ or $P=[3,2,4,1] . P$ is said to be sorted if the numbers are in increasing order. Which of the statements are true?

> **A)** The arrangement $[9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]$ can be sorted in 8 moves and no fewer.
> **B)** $[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2]$ can be sorted in 8 moves and no fewer.
> **C)** $[1,3,4,2,9,5,6,7,8]$ cannot be sorted by any number of moves.

> **D)** There exists an arrangement of 99 numbers, i.e. 1 to 99 , that cannot be sorted by any number of moves.

- > What i thought was that to check by doing myself if the given arragemne is sorted or not , i was able to solve A sequence in 14 moves first interchanging 1 and 8 , then $(9-1), (1-7),(8-1),(1-6),(7-1),(1-5),(6-1),(1-4),(5-1),(1-3),(4-1),(1-2),(3-1)$. But i dont know how to show that whether this is minimum or not ? Is there a strategic way we can minimize it ? For B one i managed to do it in 9 moves $(1-9),(9-1),(8-1),(7-1),(6-1),(5-1),(4-1),(3-1),(2-1)$ is the 8 moves possible ?  The C part i was able to do it in 12 moves , so its wrong . From these all i thought that we can manage to do every possible sequence but is it true in case of 99 ?

> Note: i was able to realize it has something to do with parity odd , even number of moves and the initial total numbers there , but couldnt progress after that at all.

Comment: Hint: How is the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) of $P$ affected by swapping two adjacent elements?

Comment: Initially it has 3 inversions (1,2), (3,4),(1,4) positions . By swapping adjacent i am just considering the sorting which the question wants so it would be either switch 3 with 1 or 1 with 4 , first will result in increase by 1 as number of inversions . Other one decrease it by 1 . How does this help ? Also motivation for checking this inversion stuff here ? @MikeEarnest

Comment: If you can prove that any adjacent swap changes the number of inversions by exactly one (as you noticed in one particular example), then you would prove that the number of swaps must be at least the number of inversions. Then, if you could show that that any permutation with $i$ inversions could be sorted with no more than $i$ adjacent swaps, you would be done.